# Difference between intrusion on/upon/of/into

Tags: meaning

Different dictionaries suggest different answers. 
One [example](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/intrusion),  suggests that all of them, except for ***of*** work. 
However, as we can see [here](https://ludwig.guru/s/intrusion+of)  the **of** structure is also possible.

There must be a difference between these four prepositions, because the following exercise (it's a part 2 -gap text, CAE task) allows ***into*** as the only possible answer:

> The camera images were checked with the national facial recognition
>   system and it has been confirmed that you were the driver. This
>   increasing intrusion ***into*** our private lives will force us to consider
>   the balance between personal freedom and the power of the state.

What is the difference in meaning between the other three possibilities - of/on/upon?

Is there a difference between them?

Why is this the only possible answer?

Comment: George, what is unclear about the differnce you cite between "of" and "on/upon/into", please? If you did enough research to clarify that, might it also make your dictionaries more clear?